# Run a PowerShell script with Administrator privileges on other computer

Tags: c#, powershell

My user haven't got access to run PowerShell.exe

Using C# I want to be able to run

```
(Get-Service -ComputerName 172.x.x.x -Name mssqlserver).Start()
```

on another computer, as the domain administrator account.

I can run PowerShell as administrator's username and password.

I searched in StackOverFlow... but I did not found my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !!!!
I build my application and run it to create application.exe
then run it as administrator !!
in this way I can run all of my scripts without any error !
:^)
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you need an administrative privilege when executing your application, you should add below element in the application's manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

For executing a PowerShell script you can also use the below link. I have used this library before and it works fine.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Comment: I can right click on Powershell.lnk and click "run as administrator" and enter user and password and run my command, but i want to do this in c# with existing administrator's username and password.

Comment: _with existing administrator's username and password._ Isn't it that, what @Payam worte? Starting your app, it would either run privileged or ask for credentials to a privileged user. Or do you try to run your code __as different user__?

Comment: @CodeMan there are two approaches to getting this done. First, you can execute the PowerShell script in C#, which is the one that I have provided. Second, you can execute a PowerShell file. Both need administrative privilege which I have included.